# Type mismatch when indexing array in VBScript with variable (Worksheet related)

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, type-mismatch, vba

I ran into some issues with Excel related VBScript. I know there's probably a straight forward solution for this that will later on seem obvious, but anyways:

All I'm trying to achieve here is basically getting the lengths of the longest values in each column and write them back to an array (one value for each of the first 16 column). Simple as that.

```
...
mlen = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
For i = 1 To 16
  rw2 = 2                        ' starting from the second row
  While Cells(rw2, i) <> ""      ' all the way until an empty field is found
    If Len(Cells(rw2, i)) > mlen(i - 1) Then mlen(i - 1) = Len(Cells(rw2, i))
    rw2 = rw2 + 1
  Wend
Next
...
```

However, it gives me a type mismatch for the "mlen(i-1)" on the right side of the ">" operator.

Any solution would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Comment: Hallo, Did you try to explicit the types in the comparison? i.e. `Len(Cells(rw2, i)) > CLng(mlen(i - 1) )`

Comment: Hello, the problem pretty much remains the same. _Calculating the value_ of mlen(i-1) itself seems to be problem, not the comparison part (or at least I believe so). :(

Comment: You are in the Excel code editor, right?

Comment: Yes, I am. This ispart of a button-click performed action.

Comment: Open the immediate window and type `?mlen(i-1)` what do you get ?

Comment: Works ok with   Dim mlen() :  Dim i As Long:  Dim rw2 As Long....How do I reproduce this? Do you have sample data?

Comment: Thanks QHarr, pre-declaring mlen() and i as long actually DID solve it. Thank you all for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

tmax <> mlen!

```
>> mlen = Array(0, 0, 0)
>> WScript.Echo mlen(0)
>> WScript.Echo tmax(0)
>>
0
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Typenkonflikt (i.e. type-mismatch)
>>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say mlen(i-1). The type mismatch is on the right side of the > operator. Updated the question, good catch, thanks :)